# Open picture in Python using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to take a screenshot of my PC and display it to me.
I have tried:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageGrab

im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save(r'D:\photo.jpg')
im.show()
```

However, it does not work, Why?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Try `im.show()` first and ensure you're capturing the image!

Comment: Which OS do you use? , `ImageGrab` is not implemented in Linux and it'll definitely throw an error at you if you try it under Linux.

Comment: It doent show me my screenshot. Just open the winsows photos and does not show it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save('photo.png') #Saving the image
img = Image.open('photo.jpg')
img.show()
```

This differs from the OP because I am using the Image library of PIL to open and show the image. The OP originally tried to display the image using the ImageGrab.grab() function.  This was incorrect. The image needs to be opened first and then shown.

Comment: why does this code work whereas the OP's code doesn't? That's the interesting part that isn't in your answer.